# Report with Formula that does not evaluate if there is a Null value

Tags: reporting, report-formula

I am trying to calculate if a support case breached the SLA time. However, I don't want to calculate the breach time if there is a null value in one of the fields. I have tried the below but get an error.

```
IF(NOT(ISNULL(Flexible_SLA_Time__c > 
    CASE(b1_case_severity__c, 
        "1 - Critical", 9.5, 
        "2 - High", 9.5, 
        "3 - Medium", 19, 
        "4 - Low", 28.5, 0),
    1,
    0
))))
```

**Error** when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You're `IF` function's `True` and `False` execution is available in wrong place. May be it's should be as follows,

```
 IF (

(NOT(ISNULL(Flexible_SLA_Time__c)) &&  (Flexible_SLA_Time__c> 
    CASE(b1_case_severity__c, 
        "1 - Critical", 9.5, 
        "2 - High", 9.5, 
        "3 - Medium", 19, 
        "4 - Low", 28.5, 0))),1, 0
)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I now receive the following error.                                                     Error when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNULL()'.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try it.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!!!